# The website with id 1 that was requested wasn't found error when migrate data using migration tool

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

During migration i face this error 
i have run the following command

```
sudo php bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check the store_website table to see whether the website with id 1 exists

Comment: in magneto 1 there is no store_website table but in magneto 2 there exist  with id 0 and id 2 not for 1

Comment: Then, you should create 1 more website and go to its DB to change the id to 1